# How can I set tflite PoseNet "Single-Person Pose Estimation" on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow-lite

I'm on a project that uses tflite Posenet to run on a mobile with Flutter Framework. We wanted more precision score on our tests, but we realized that the repository which is given us by the original example on Dart API docs https://pub.dev/documentation/tflite/latest/ uses Multi-Person Pose Estimation by defalt. (Repository mentioned:https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_realtime_detection).

We know that the original tfjs repository talks about it and give examples https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet but we can't find it on Dart API for flutter.

How can I set Single-Person Pose Estimation?

Answer (score 2):

There is another `tflite_flutter` plugin which is actively being developed: https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter. Please take a look.

This plugin allows you to run any custom `.tflite` model, so you should be able to download the single person posenet model provided from the official TFLite site here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview.

There aren't any official flutter examples, but you should be able to refer to the Android/iOS examples to see how to pre-process / post-process the data.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful

Comment: @DanielDantas did you succeeded to do that?

Comment: Read this article for better understanding https://medium.com/flutter-community/posenet-for-ios-android-and-flutter-using-tensorflow-lite-836788a110c7

Comment: Hy @jacobgalam ! Yeah, we take some tests with the Tflite.runPoseNetOnImage function. Basicaly, this function has a property called numResults, wich we can set to "1". Hope you can achieve your goal !

Answer (score 2):

Hy guys, updating the issue:

We maneged it after some tests with the Tflite.runPoseNetOnImage function. This function has a property called numResults, wich we can set to "1". Tflite.runPoseNetOnFrame has the same property.

You can see it in this link (https://pub.dev/documentation/tflite/latest/)